# accordion of div's

Tags: jquery

I am making an accordion of Div's here is the code:

```
 $('.answer').hide();
 $('.question').click (function(){
    $('.answer').slideUp();
    $('#question'+$(this).attr('target')).slideDown('slow');
 })
```

It is working fine, but I want it so when I click again on same question it closes.
Here is the HTML I used :

```
<h1 class="question" target="1">Some Question</h1>
<p id="question1" class="answer">Some Answer</p>
<h1 class="question" target="2">Another question</h1>
<p id="question2" class="answer">Another answer</p>
```

Thanks in advance

please look the code here : http://jsfiddle.net/FMLhc/

Comment: You should include the HTML structure too, so we can see how you're setting up the ID's and such.  There could be a huge difference between `$('#question' + $(this)...` and `$('#question ' + $(this)...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

http://jsfiddle.net/FMLhc/15/

Basically, just check the state of the toggle, and do what you need to do.